# Adding new server to Farm not firing event receivers

Tags: sharepoint, server-farm, feature-activation

Experts-

We have deployed WSP (with features and feature activation event receivers) in farm environment. Event receivers creates timer jobs to perform few changes to all servers in farm.

Issue:

When new server is added to farm, WSP is getting deployed automatically(can see deployed files), but event receivers are not being fired on newly added server. Hence missing our project related configuration changes in new server.

Please suggest .

Bala

Comment: We realized that this can't be done and known limitation.